# How do I get the product ID when I submit the form?

Tags: forms, commerce

How do I get the product ID when I submit the form?

[image]

I have http://localhost/drupalcart/product/7?v=7 as URL. I need to get that 7 when I click on *Add to cart*.

(The form doesn't come from a third-party, but it's something I made.)

Comment: Shouldn't the product id be a hidden field in the form?

Comment: If that so... how can i get that ID.. thats my question bro

Comment: I have no idea how your form is constructed, most people stick to the add to cart form that comes with Drupal Commerce. But one way is to grab the entity ID the product is assigned to, and get the value from it.

Comment: I've constructed the form by this way:

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form['qty']    = array(
            '#type'         =>  'number',
            '#title'        =>  t('Quantity: '),
            '#required'     =>  TRUE,
            '#attributes'   =>  array('min' => 1, 'max'=>100)
        );
        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type'         =>  'submit',
            '#value'        =>  t('Add to Cart'),
            '#button_type'  =>  'primary'
        );
        return $form;
    }

Comment: In that case as your suggestion... I should add an input hidden with the product id right?... so how do i catch the ID :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys finally i got the solution to it, all that I need it was the following:

```
$product_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_product')->id();
```

then I got the product id of the product i am checking it